# How to find latest data in a joined result

Tags: sql

I have three tables.
table A :

| version | type |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | A |
| 02 | B |

the version is unique key.

table B:

| id | version | item | createtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | 1 | 2023-02-12 |
| 2 | 01 | 1 | 2023-03-12 |

table C:

| tableBid | name | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test01 | 8 |
| 2 | test02 | 7 |

I wrote below SQL to find latest detail for each type in table A

```
select * 
from A 
left join B 
  on A.version=B.version 
left join C 
  on B.id=C.ableBd 
where A.version in (
   select max(version) from A group by type
   )
```

But in table B same version can have different createtime, how to modify this SQL to get the latest createtime result only?The expected result of above data should be
|version |type |id| version| item |createtime  |tableBid|name  |qty |
|--------|-----|--|--------|------|------------|--------|------|----|
|  01    |  A  | 2|   01   |   1  |  2023-03-12|1       |test01|8   |
|  02    |  B  |  |        |      |            |        |      |    |
Thx.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't really match your question. Even if we were to change it so to return the max "detail" from B it wouldn't match the join with the only row in C so no rows. Please fix that and also add what would be the expected result from your sample data so we don't need to guess

Comment: A [mcve] should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.name, c.qty, b.version, b.item, a.type, MAX(b.createtime)
from C
join B 
  on B.id=C.tableBid
join A
  on A.version=B.version
group by c.name, c.qty, b.version, b.item, a.type
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
       JOIN b ON a.version = b.version
       JOIN c ON b.id = c.tableBid
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   a a1
                   WHERE  a1.type = a.type AND a1.version > a.version)
       AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   b b1
                   WHERE  b1.version = b.version AND b1.createtime > b.createtime)
```